# When adding the header file in the .cpp file, errors arise

Tags: c++

The Nodes.h file alone when compiled works, however when I include it in the Nodes.cpp file, all the errors arise, such as missing type specifier - `int` assumed at line 11,12,13 . Also another error is syntax error: identifier  `'ASTSimpleExpressionNode'`. Is it something that I am doing wrong. Can't I specify how my struct can be constructed by defining the different constructors?
For now the `ASTSimpleExpressionNode` is empty because if I continued the process it would duplicate all the errors.

Some of the errors:

> Error C2535   'ASTExpressionNode::ASTExpressionNode(void)': member
>   function already defined or declared [line 16] Error  C4430   missing
>   type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int   [Line 11, 12,13 so on.] Error   C2143   syntax error: missing
>   ';' before '*' [Line 11,12,13] unexpected token(s) preceding ';' [Line
>   11,12,13]

Nodes.h file.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct ASTNode
{

};

struct ASTExpressionNode : ASTNode
{
    ASTSimpleExpressionNode *left;
    ASTRelationOperatorNode *rel_op;
    ASTSimpleExpressionNode *right;

    ASTExpressionNode(ASTSimpleExpressionNode *l);
    ASTExpressionNode(ASTSimpleExpressionNode *l, ASTRelationOperatorNode *op, ASTSimpleExpressionNode *r);
};

struct ASTSimpleExpressionNode : ASTExpressionNode
{

};

struct ASTRelationOperatorNode :ASTExpressionNode
{
    string rel_op;

    ASTRelationOperatorNode(string op);
};
```

Nodes.cpp file.

```
#include "Nodes.h"
```

Comment: ASTNode has to have a virtual method if you are going to use polymorphism on a struct but the way you are declaring pointers I think ASTExpressionNode needs access to instances of other structs too. Just a guess hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward-declare `ASTSimpleExpressionNode` and `ASTRelationOperatorNode`:

```
struct ASTSimpleExpressionNode;
struct ASTRelationOperatorNode;

struct ASTExpressionNode : ASTNode
{
   // etc
```